# ASP.NET Identity core exception error on custom user class

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I created a custom class called "ApplicationUser" which extends the Identity user. However, when I try to access the "ApplicationUser" though user manager in a MVC controller, it gives the following error.

```
**An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.**

InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Xmoor.Models.ApplicationUser]' while attempting to activate 'Xmoor.Main.Areas.GeneralStaff.Controllers.HomeController'.
```

The following code is the definition of "Application User"

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Xmoor.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser:IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string OtherNames { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public int? staffId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(nameof(staffId))]
        public StaffPersonalDetails staffPersonalDetails { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// This field is used to check whether current user is registred or not.
        /// This should accept "COMPLETE","INPROGRESS","REQUESTED","UNREQUESTED" 
        /// </summary>
        public string RegStatus { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// This field is used to check whether the current user is an applicant or an employee.
        /// </summary>
        public string UserStatus { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The following code shows the DBcontext setup.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using Xmoor.Models;

namespace Xmoor.DataAccess
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

        

        /// <summary>
        /// As the NI number is unique, a unique constaint is added to the database.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            builder.Entity<StaffPersonalDetails>().HasIndex(user => user.NationalInsuranceNumber).IsUnique();
            builder.Entity<StaffPersonalDetails>().Property(user => user.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd().UseIdentityColumn(1000, 1);
        }

        public DbSet<Salary> Salary { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Department> Department { get; set; }
        public DbSet<StaffPersonalDetails> StaffPersonalDetails { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ApplicationUser> Linker { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Roles> Roles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Employment> Employments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ShiftRecord> ShiftRecords { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Holidays> Holidays { get; set; }
        public DbSet<HolidayRecord> HolidayRecords { get; set; }

    }
}
```

The following code show the configuration of "program.cs" file.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
        builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
    )) ;

builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddDefaultTokenProviders().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender,EmailSender>();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
var app = builder.Build();
```

The following code shows the Controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Xmoor.DataAccess;
using Xmoor.Models;

namespace Xmoor.Main.Areas.GeneralStaff.Controllers
{
    [Area("GeneralStaff")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

        public  HomeController( UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried changing the `AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()` to `AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()`. However, the error moved from "ApplicationUser" to "IdentityUser" when I did that.

Please can someone help me to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to replace the following line in your **program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddDefaultTokenProviders().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

with below

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>().AddDefaultTokenProviders().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

in short, since u have extended the `IdentityUser` to `ApplicationUser`, you have to use the `ApplicationUser` as the generic type

Comment: I did try to do that. It worked in the mvc controller but gave the same error in Scaffolded sign up page

Comment: in the sign up page also you must  inject the `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` and not `UserManager<IdentityUser>`